# How to copy images using amoeba gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amoeba-gem

I am using amoeba gem for duplicating record and i am using carrierwave for uploading images.

I tried to copy the images from the associated model using amoeba, it only copies the data from the original record(it copies only icon name,file attributes in the database), but the images are not present in filesystem (in Public folder)

This is my model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  self.class.amoeba do
    include_field [:images]
  end
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

I used the following method

```
duplicate = @book.amoeba_dup
duplicate.save
```

I tried with the following in Book model

```
amoeba do
    include_field :images
end
```

Help me to solve this

Comment: How do you copy the images?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have edited my question. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following to image model:

```
  amoeba do
     customize(lambda { |original_object,new_object|
       new_object.image = original_object.image
     })
  end
```

OR if you even has the attachment in same model you can use same code in the model itself, the idea behind is you need to assign the paperclip object itself and without this part it only copy paperclip fileds for file name, file size and file type withour copy the attachment file itself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't any experience with this gem but Have you tried by adding below code to the `Book` model

```
amoeba do
    enable
  end
```

for more details refer this **[documentation](https://github.com/rocksolidwebdesign/amoeba#readme)**  this may help you

Comment: Yes, i tried with the above code. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: for images if you had used paper_clip then use include_field [:avatar]

Answer (score 0):

```
customize(lambda { |original_object, new_object|
  new_object.picture.attach(original_object.picture.blob) if original_object.picture.attached?
})
```

This worked for me